# "Took into consideration" or "Taken into consideration"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, past-tense

Do I say "took into consideration" or "taken into consideration"? For example, do I say when looking at shoes, "The first thing "took/taken" into consideration is how fashionable they are."?

Comment: This is an example of 'whiz-deletion': 'The first thing [which was/had been/is/will be] taken into consideration ...' so the _ed_-form (past participle) remains as the correct form. This has been covered here many times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The first thing taken into consideration

is correct, **not**

> The first thing took into consideration.

This is because the verb "to take" here appears in the **passive** mood, which always takes the past participle (here "taken") and not the simple past "took".